# How do you set the accessibility label on an image that is drawn with Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-ui-automation

I am trying to write UIAutomation tests around some core graphics logic.  Currently we are using core graphics to draw an image.  I'm trying to set the accessibility label/identifier/value on the image so that I can verify its presence via a UIAutomation test, but no matter what I do I'm not getting the accessibility label/identifier/value on the DOM in my test.  Here are the things I have tried:

Setting directly on the image.

```
UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithData:bfCaseStudy.image];
uiImage.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
uiImage.accessibilityLabel = bfCaseStudy.name;
uiImage.accessibilityValue = bfCaseStudy.name;
uiImage.accessibilityIdentifier = bfCaseStudy.name;

CGContextDrawImage(context, [self rectForAttr:bfCaseStudy], uiImage.CGImage);
```

Setting on the Core Image

```
UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithData:bfCaseStudy.image];
uiImage.CIImage.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
uiImage.CIImage.accessibilityLabel = bfCaseStudy.name;
uiImage.CIImage.accessibilityValue = bfCaseStudy.name;

CGContextDrawImage(context, [self rectForAttr:bfCaseStudy], uiImage.CGImage);
```

Either way produces the same result.  Here is the UIAutomation code trying to access the information.

```
UIALogger.logDebug(bookTwoHelper.mainWindow.images()[5].label());
UIALogger.logDebug(bookTwoHelper.mainWindow.images()[5].name());
UIALogger.logDebug(bookTwoHelper.mainWindow.images()[5].value());

Debug: (2013-02-25 16:06:33 +0000) - (null)
Debug: (2013-02-25 16:06:33 +0000) - (null)
Debug: (2013-02-25 16:06:33 +0000) - (null)
```

Here is the relevant portion of the DOM

```
UIAImage "(null)" {{0, 149}, {316, 55}}
```

Is there a way to set an accessibility label/identifier/value on an image that is drawn using core graphics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties like `accessibilityLabel` will only work when used with UIKit controls like `UIView`, `UIImageView` etc. Because your image isn't a real `UIView`, you will need to provide extra information to UIKit by making your container view or view controller implement the `UIAccessibilityContainer` protocol.

See the [Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more information, particularly [Make the Contents of Custom Container Views Accessible.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW10)